# Почему в GULPe не переносится html-файл в папку dist?

Tags: gulp

Почему GULP не переносит html-файл в папку dist?

```
**gulpfile.js**
==================
'use strict';

const gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('html', () => {
    return gulp.src('./src/index.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
==================
**package.json**
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "core-js": "^3.4.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  }
======================
Команда: gulp html
Starting 'html'...
Finished 'html' after 18 ms
======================
Но!!! Файл не переносится(копируется) в папку dist?!
```

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае надо было переустановить node.js(обязательно ver.LTS), очистить кеш - npm cache clean --force. Ну и переустановить npm-пакеты